# I'm curious why my latest answer on Stack Overflow was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, undelete-request

I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16905524/1801312) on Stack Overflow and I'm not sure why it was deleted. I went back to look at it and I didn't see anything wrong with my answer that would cause it to be deleted.

Comment: Do you have a link to the answer?

Comment: I'm betting you posted something should have been a comment, it was flagged as such and removed. Just a note: we don't have "forums." Forums are for back and forth conversation loosely centered around some topic. We don't have that. We have questions that we want answered. That's it.

Comment: the link to the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16905524/1801312

Comment: Yeah, that's not an answer.

Comment: the forum is asking about deploying with git so I posted that I created a deployment tool and included a link.

Comment: Note that the highest voted answer on that question links to some code, but then _outlines the specific steps involved_. See the difference?

Comment: should I post it as a comment?

Comment: You can't, you have not earned that ability. Post some useful answers or well received questions and then you can post comments to other questions/answers.

Comment: so how should I post it? I could include that my repo has instructions on how to use the tool I created.

Comment: We're looking for answers that will withstand the possible future destruction of your repo. Note that someone reading the accepted answer on that question could recreate the solution even if the link to the code broke. Model your answers after stuff like that.

Comment: I just deleted copy number 3. I recommend not reposting until you fully understand what's going on.

Comment: Is there any way I can just delete my accounts? It shouldn't be this difficult to post an answer. I went through others answers and many are less informative than mine.

Comment: like the one that says    I found this one and it works really great:

http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

Comment: For the record; other posts there have been flagged and deleted, too.

Comment: Not really an answer...

Answer (score 4):

The question:

> Is it possible to deploy a PHP website using git push? I have a hunch it has something to do with using git hooks to perform a git reset --hard on the server side, but how would I go about accomplishing this?

You answer doesn't answer this question, and seems to only advertise your own tool, hence why it would have been deleted:

> I finally released my deployment tool I've been working on for some time. there are 3 repos to separate the development code from the staging code from the production code. its intended use is to have different permissions for each repository so once a developer is done testing on the development server QA can push the code to the staging server and test it. Then once they have QAed the code a manager or whomever is authorised can push the code to production. The tool is available on github at...

*Perhaps you could have linked to your project as a comment, but to be honest I'm not sure whether this kind of advertising of your own products is entirely appropriate.*

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is a link-only answer which is discouraged. Links break and such posts get useless.

Besides that you are only promoting a tool you developed. That is discouraged too.

Comment: It's not link only?

Comment: Well there is text in the answer too, but I can't see anything substantial in there besides saying OP developed that tool.

Comment: Yup; it's not so much "link only", as "nothing but promoting the link".